# Finding the min first value of a list of pairs of numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, apply

I have a list of "tuples" in javascript, something like `[[1,2], [2,4], [3,5], [5,2], ..., [x, y]]` and I would like to find the minimum of the first values in such a way that I can get both values of the "tuple". So in this case I would get the value `[1,2]`. This seems like something that could be done with the `apply` function, but I am somewhat new to some of the finer points in JavaScript like the `apply` function. Could anyone help me out with getting started with doing this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the use for `apply()` here. This is more like a job for a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sirko said, you can do that with a simple `for` loop, comparing each first value with its previous value. You can also do that with the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)<sup>1</sup> array method, to achieve shorter code:

```
var tuples = [[1,2], [2,4], [3,5], [5,2]];
var tupleWithMinFirstValue = tuples.reduce(function(previous, current){
    return current[0] < previous[0] ? current : previous;
}, [Infinity]);
console.log(tupleWithMinFirstValue);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wAGMX/

<sup>1</sup> The link also provides compatibility info, and a polyfill.